# C# - DataGridView and SelectedCells - Finding the Row Indexes of Selected Cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

What is the cleanest way to ask a DataGridView to return "indexes of rows that have selected cells"? This is not the same as DataGridView.SelectedRows. I don't allow Row or Column selection. So users must select blocks of cells. I just need to find out which rows have selected cells in them.

Is there some clever lambda expression I should be using? 
What would you do?

*If this helps*:
In the code I am writing I have already inherited from DataGridView and I'm in my own custom class DataGridViewExt.

Comment: I feel like there should be some kind of SELECT DISTINCT in LINQ syntax that I should be doing.

Comment: Should be doing or could be doing?

Comment: Should be - in the sense that someone else will support this codebase a year from now... And if I can describe the intent in 1 line rather than 3 to 5 that would be better for this project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LINQ solution:

```
var rowIndexes = dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                  .Select(cell => cell.RowIndex)
                                  .Distinct();
```

**Edit:**

You were just missing the Cast. It's needed because DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection doesn't implement a generic `IEnumerable<DataGridViewCell>`, just `IEnumerable`, so when you enumerate the values, they are of type `Object`. With the cast, that would give:

```
int[] rowIndexes = (from sc in this.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>() 
                    select sc.RowIndex).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: awesome! +1 and answer. just curious but what would the alternate syntax be? I got tripped up somewhere: int[] rowIndexes = (from sc in this.SelectedCells select sc.RowIndex).Distinct().ToArray(); can you add that to the answer?

Comment: Ah ok. Need to read an article or two on LINQ and .Cast<>(). Thanks.

Comment: Getting this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'. I have datagrid not datagridview.. I'm doing a WPF not Windows form app. Can u help me? :(

Comment: @goodfriend: Sorry this is a winforms solution only and I'm not familiar enough with WPF to know the answer in that technology.

Comment: @Meta-Knight it's ok I found out myself :D

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<int> indexes = 
 (from c in dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
  select c.RowIndex).Distinct();
```